# Маппить ResultSet к Entity обьектам

Tags: java, jdbc, mapper, resultset

Пишу учебный проект.
Моя проблема - я не знаю как написать универсальный маппер `ResultSet` на объекты, без Hibernate и без Spring. На чистом JDBC.
Я начал пытаться писать, и столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Пример: есть у меня Entity-обьект `TASK`(Поручение), у него есть две зависимости (или два поля) с другой таблицей `Person`. С именами `EXECUTOR`(Исполнитель) и `AUTHOR`(Поручитель).
И когда я отправляю вот такой запрос

```
SELECT * FROM TASK T

JOIN PERSON P2 on P2.ID = T.EXECUTOR

JOIN PERSON P3 on T.AUTHOR = P3.ID WHERE T.ID=?.
```

Мне приходят данные с двух одинаковых таблиц. И как отличать при маппинге, данные предназначенные для `EXECUTOR`(Исполнитель) от данных предназначенные для `AUTHOR`(Поручитель)?
Надеюсь понятно объяснил. Заранее спасибо.

```
public class Task{

private Person EXECUTOR;

private Person AUTHOR;
```

Comment: Не использовать * в селекте, а дать "человеческие" именам полям выборки. Я надеюсь вы потом к полям при переборе не по их id обращаетесь?

Comment: А алиасы, которые вы объявляете вам на что?